Is it possible to get external data directly from function parameters in solidity?
Blockchain fetches external data through Oracle.
Is it possible for a user calling a smart contract function to upload external data as parameters to the smart contract when calling the function?

Hey, not sure I understand. If you want to spend gas to update a contracts value, you can do it. I can't imagine any protocol using chainlink oracles for price updates would be storing arbitrary user data, but can you write a contract with slots to store whatever you like and repeatedly push updates every block to change those values, sure.

Thank you for your suggestion.
It means that the user can upload external data to the smart contract by setting function parameters. But it will incur more expensive gas overhead. right？

Exactly. So a limiting factor is that you can't make an api call to an off chain source from a contract (it's why chainlink is a thing), but you can push updates to a contracts storage, and this is what for example a lending protocol does with chainlink on each interaction with a market. So as to update the price before anything else happens.

Yes, users can call functions of contracts to update data, while Oracle like Chainlink helps you to fetch the data in a decentralized manner.
